# "if the majority of the players is honest", is vs are

Tags: grammatical-number

A friend of mine came across an academic paper which consistently used the phrase "if the majority of the players is honest....". I'm pretty sure that that "is" ought to be an "are", but it was pointed out that if you changed it to "if the majority is honest..." then "is" would be appropriate, even though the subject doesn't really change plurality, so now we're not sure.

So the question is: is the first form correct (though strange sounding)? And if not, what makes it different from the second?

Thanks!

Comment: Could be a UK/US thing, but in the US it would be "are".  Only if "majority" were being used to refer to something like a voting bloc would "is" be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

I have difficulty editing such prose. Majority and minority are clearly singular, as in "Those who voted yes are in a majority". Nevertheless, when attention focusses on those who comprise the majority, I commonly see examples such "The majority are fools". It is pedantic and may be prolix and awkward to re-cast such examples, so I permit the plural use.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times when technical usage doesn't match popular usage.

"The majority" is singular. That is, there is one majority, so we should say "the majority is... ." However, this sounds strange to us, since it is not the majority which is honest, but the people in the majority who are.

Personally I would use "are" in most contexts, and, if it were being published, consider rephrasing.

Comment: I would +1 if you didn't write that last sentence.  The majority **is** singular, just as you pointed out.  You shouldn't back up what you just argued against.

Comment: I believe it is more important to communicate effectively (which I believe means follow the social norm) than to follow "technical" rules, but that a matter of opinion.

Comment: Not saying that I myself would never accidentally use *are* instead, but doing so *would* be an accident.

Comment: In most uses "the majority" is referring to a selection of people or other entities, just as "a few" does.  You wouldn't say "a few is".

Comment: @dockeryZ ... I addressed this over on [ELU](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/31841/32) last year. Briefly, *majority* in contexts like this is slipping out of its full-nominal sense and into the sense which *CGEL* calls a "number-transparent quantificational noun". Compare *a lot of people*, *a number of people*, *plenty of people*.

Comment: Interesting analysis @StoneyB.   My conclusion is that English is just too hard to keep on track.  Consistency is sacrificed for semantics too often and it's left up to native speakers to explain why, and we never can, and we probably never will be able to.

Comment: we can't keep it on track because there is no track. think of how different english was as recently as 300 years ago.

Comment: So from what I'm gathering the final answer is that "is" is technically correct for both cases, but "are" just sounds right to me for the first because that's how I happen to speak?

Comment: @dockeryZ: I find it remarkable to see your formalist attitude to number congruence combined with what looks to me like the very recent practice of giving up past perfect in favour of simple past ("if you didn't write" instead of "if you hadn't written"). The only commonality seems to be that both contradict the practices of the best English writers.

Answer (score 0):

Both forms are correct. Which is better stylistically depends on fine nuances of meaning and on the variant of English used. One can also construct examples where one form or the other is obviously better, or even required:

> The majority of the players do not cheat each other.
>
> The majority of the players to which cheating is foreign is overwhelming.

In the first example, we are clearly thinking of the individual players. In the second example, we are treating the non-cheating players as an anonymous mass. Obviously, an anonymous mass cannot cheat 'each other', and a bunch of individuals can't be individually 'overwhelming'. One difference that is often encountered is sports teams. In British English, "Manchester play Birmingham" etc., whereas most American ears would expect a singular verb here. (I can't think of a reverse example right now, but from my time as a Wikipedia editor I remember that those cases exist as well. Maybe someone can provide one.)

Many uses of "the majority of the players" (and similar constructions) will be ambiguous between these two meanings. For these, the choice really depends on the writer's intent and the defaults set by the writer's variant of English. E.g. there are contexts in which British English prefers *are* and American English prefers *is*, and others in which the reverse is true.

In some languages the verb must agree formally with the subject. For various reasons, non-native speakers may be under the impression that English works that way. This can lead to an over-use of the singular with plural nouns in academic papers. But in most cases that's a stylistic problem rather than a grammatical one.